# Bounded linear operators and inner product spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

If I suppose that H is an inner product space with inner produce $\int_{0}^{1} \alpha(t) \beta(t) dt$.  If I define $T: H \to H$ by $T(\alpha)(t) = \int_{0}^{t} \alpha(u) dt$

How would I show that:

1) $T\in L_b(H,H)$

2) $||T^2|| \leq 1/2$

3) $||T^2|| > 1/3$

For 1) I used the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and said:

$(T(\alpha)(t))^2 \leq \int_{0}^{t} \alpha(u)du \int_{0}^{t} \alpha(u)du$

$(\int_{0}^{t} \alpha(u)du)^2 \leq (\alpha)(t)(\alpha)(t)$

$(\alpha(t))^2 \leq (\alpha(t),\alpha(t))$

$(\alpha(t)*\alpha(t)) \leq (\alpha,\alpha)(t)$

$(\alpha, \alpha)(t) \leq (\alpha, \alpha)(t)$

Since $(\alpha,\alpha)(t) = (\alpha,\alpha,)(t)$ I have show that $T \in L_b(H,H)$.  Have I shown this correctly?  Does anyone know how to show the other two parts.  Thanks for any  suggestions/help!

Answer (score 0):

Since we have $\|T^2\| \leq \|T\|^2$, we just need to show $\|T\| \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$ for (1) and (2). You might want to look up the integral form of Minkovski's inequality. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality#Minkowski.27s_integral_inequality

$$\|T\alpha\|=\left( \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^t\alpha(s)\;ds\right)^2\;dt\right)^\frac{1}{2}\\
=\left( \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^1 \mathbb{1}_{s<t}\cdot\alpha(s)\;ds\right)^2\;dt\right)^\frac{1}{2} \\
\leq \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^1 (\mathbb{1}_{s<t}\cdot\alpha(s))^2\;dt\right)^\frac{1}{2}\;ds\\
\leq \int_0^1 \alpha(s)\left( \int_0^1 \mathbb{1}_{s<t}\;dt\right)^\frac{1}{2}\;ds \\
\leq \int_0^1 \alpha(s)\sqrt{1-s}\;ds\\
(\text{By Cauchy Schwarz:)} \\
\leq \sqrt{\int_0^1\alpha(s)^2\;ds}\cdot \sqrt{\int_0^1(\sqrt{1-s})^2\;ds}\\
\leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\|\alpha\|
$$
Therefore, $\|T\|\leq\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: Thanks Zach.  So in order to show it is >1/3, is it mostly the same? and did I show the first part of the question right?

Comment: I found it was difficult to read your proof… For the third part, it is enough to find one $\alpha$ such that $\|T^2\alpha\|$ > $1/3\|\alpha\|$.

Comment: I was pretty much taking Cauchy Shwartz inequality and integrating both sides of the equation to show that $(\alpha,\alpha)(t) \leq (\alpha, \alpha)(t)$ and since they are equal that $T \in L_b(H,H)$.  Is there a better way to show that $T \in L_b(H,H)$?